# Push commands to OpenWRT router via php

Tags: php, console, openwrt, router, telnet

I've developed a static webpage hosted via an OpenWRT firmware based router and would like to create a reset button held on that page, the console command is:

```
reboot
```

I'm struggling to work out the logic to do this. I have permissions to allow for it however. Could anyone offer advice or any articles around this subject? Thanks in advance

Comment: tried using telnet, but the router doesn't seem to handle the command correctly, or my code logic is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system of pages must be written with lines using echo within a bash script to allow this functionality